# How do we evaluate this limit -- a product of a series, which is entire, and a decaying exponential function,

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, limits-without-lhopital

$$lim_{s-> \infty}\phi(sz)e^{-s}$$

where $\phi$ is the series $$\sum_0^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}(sz)^n$$ and is **entire**.

Also, assume that we have this upper bound: $|\phi(sz)|$ $\le$M$e^{|sz|}$.

Then, we can look at this limit instead:

$$lim_{s-> \infty}\ Me^{s(|z|-1)}$$

which is just zero for |z| < 1 easily -- but it is *not* zero for |z| =1 or |z|>1.

Note: s is real, while z is complex.

Thanks,

Comment: $\phi(sz)$ is undefined for $|z|>1$, so the limit has no sense

Comment: Hi, @Tryss - I transcribed the series incorrectly and have edited my question just now to show the correct series.  Also, I've added the upper bound that we are allowed to assume.

Comment: I made a few errors in my posting of this question, and hopefully I have caught it all now and edited my question completely -- phi is assumed to be **entire**, with the upper bound assumption, too, @Tryss.  What do you think? Thanks,